# Can't find a field for some reason in a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class identifierModel(models.Model):
    identifierField = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True),
    ipField = models.CharField(max_length=15),
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from getidentifier.models import identifierModel


def commands(request, identifier):
    if identifier in identifierModel.objects.all():
        return HttpResponse("ok")  # only for testing is "ok"
    else:
        HttpResponse.status_code = 401
        return HttpResponse(identifierModel.objects.filter(identifierField=identifier).exists()
                            )
```

**Error:**

> FieldError at /commands/d984b583c27f4b84a7d39b1a3a44c54e/
> Cannot resolve keyword 'identifierField' into field. Choices are: id

[image: Error from browser]

I both ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` but still its the same thing, I really don't get why it doesn't find `identifierField`, sorry if it was an obvious error I didn't see.

Comment: what is your primary ke?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
def commands(request, identifier):
    try:
        identifier_obj = identifierModel.objects.get(identifierField=identifier)
        return HttpResponse("ok")
    except identifierModel.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=401)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i just needed to remove the commas inside identifierModel

```
identifierField = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)  -->,<--
ipField = models.CharField(max_length=15)   -->,<--
```